# How do you show that a state is a simultaneous eigenstate of $\hat L_z$ and $\hat L^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, commutator

what is the general process for showing that a given state is a simultaneous eigenstate of the angular momentum operators $\hat L_z$ and $\hat L^2$? I've searched for a while but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Comment: Can't you just write out the state and the operators in some basis and check explicitly?

Comment: @NiharKarve Hi Nihar, how do you mean?

Comment: @mangoquasarplum do you know how to check if a state is an eigenstate of just $\hat L_z$?

Comment: Take a state and and apply these operators. If they come out as before, just scaled up or down, they *are* states.

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar thanks for the reply. Do you mean apply each of these operators to the eigenstate in question?

Comment: @anonymous nope :(

Comment: Update: I got it guys :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate on the answer through a different approach.

Suppose that A and B are hermitian operators, then the so-called *simultaneous diagonalization theorem* holds.
The thereom states that $[A,B] = 0 \:$ if and only if there exists an orthonormal basis such that both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal with respect to that basis, that is you can express $A=\sum_i a_i |i\rangle \langle i|$ and $B=\sum_i b_i |i\rangle \langle i|$, where $\{|i\rangle\}$ is some common orthonormal set of eigenvectors for A and B.

Since $L^{2}$ and $L_z$ are hermitian operators, if we can prove that they commute, i.e. that $[L^{2},L_z] = 0$, then, since the previous theorem holds, they share some common orthonormal set of eigenvectors. Then, as pointed out by [Nihar Karve](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/231159/nihar-karve), we can find out if a given state is a simultaneous eigenstate of $L_z$ and $L^{2}$.

So let's see that $L^{2}$ and $L_z$ commute:

\begin{align}
[L^{2},L_z] & = [L_x^2 + L_y^2  +L_z^2,L_z] \\
 & = [L_x^2,L_z] + [L_y^2,L_z]  +[L_z^2,L_z] \\
& = [L_xL_x,L_z] + [L_yL_y,L_z]  +[L_zL_z,L_z] \\
& = Lx[Lx,Lz]+[Lx,Lz]Lx + L_y[L_y,L_z]+[L_y,L_z]L_y  +L_z[L_z,L_z]+[L_z,L_z]L_z \\
& = L_x(-i\hslash L_y)+(-i\hslash L_y)L_x + L_y(i\hslash L_x)+(i\hslash L_x)L_y  +0+0 \\
& = 0 \\
\end{align}

Then, if $ |\psi\rangle$ is a given eigenvector of $L_z$, we have:

$$ L_z|\psi\rangle = \lambda |\psi\rangle $$

Applying $L^{2}$ to both side of this equation we obtain:

$$L^{2}L_z|\psi\rangle = L^{2}\lambda |\psi\rangle =  \lambda L^{2} |\psi\rangle  $$

Since the operators commute, we have:

$$L_z \bigl( L^{2}|\psi\rangle \bigr) =  \lambda \bigl( L^{2} |\psi\rangle \bigr)  $$

This equation expresses the fact that $L^{2} |\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Now, there can be two cases:

- if $\lambda$ is a non-degenerate eigenvalue, then $L^{2} |\psi\rangle$ is necessarily proportional to $|\psi\rangle$, thus $|\psi\rangle$ is also eigenvector of  $L^{2}$;
- if $\lambda$ is a degenerate eigenvalue, it can only be said that $L^{2} |\psi\rangle$ belongs to the eigensubspace $E_\lambda$ of $L_z$ and that $E_\lambda$ is invariant under the action of $L^{2}$.

Hope it can help.

Comment: The fifth line of your calculation of $[L^2,L_z]$ doesn't evaluate to zero because $L_x$ and $L_y$ don't commute.  The problem is in the preceding line - one has in general that $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$, so terms of the form $[L_xL_x,L_z]$ should expand to $L_x[L_x,L_z]+[L_x,L_z]L_x$. If you fix that, it will all work out.

Comment: I would add, however, that the commutation of $L^2$ and $L_z$ is an irrelevant fact here; two operators do not need to commute in order to have simultaneous eigenstates, and if they *do* commute a generic eigenstate of one is not an eigenstate of the other. In that sense, $[L^2,L_z]=0$ yields no information whatsoever about whether a particular state is a simultaneous eigenstate of $L^2$ and $L_z$.

Comment: I edited the calculation, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can show this by considering commutable operators (just like in the question)

$$[A,B]=0$$

let

$$A|\alpha\rangle=a|\alpha\rangle$$

now apply operator $B$ then name $B|\alpha\rangle=|\beta \rangle$

$$BA|\alpha \rangle = Ba|\alpha\rangle=a|\beta \rangle$$

based on the commutation relation, you get

$$BA|\alpha\rangle =AB|\alpha \rangle=A|\beta\rangle$$

From these last two equations it's clear that $|\beta\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $A$. This is true if $|\beta\rangle=b|\alpha\rangle$, check out

$$B|\alpha\rangle = |\beta\rangle =b|\alpha\rangle$$

you know $|\alpha\rangle$ is an eigenket of $A$ with eigenvalue "$a$" and now it's an eigenket of $B$ with eigenvalue "b". So commuting operators have simultaneous eigenkets.

Note: $[L^2, L_z]=0$

**Edit**

It was my bad, I misread the question. Above answer is to show how commutable operators like $L^2$ and $L_z$ have simultaneous eigenkets. It's easier to show if a state is eigenstate or not, you need to apply the operators to the given state and see if your eigenstates are rescaled.

Comment: Alright cool thanks! So I applied each operator on the eigenstate and for Lz operator I got 0 since the Lz operator is in terms of phi but the state was in terms of theta. Would I just say that it was shifted to zero with energy eigenvalue 0?

Comment: $L_z Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi) =m\hbar Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)$ where $L_z = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. It would be way better if you could write everything explicitly because I didn't understand what's $0$ and how does the states look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already given the state $| \psi \rangle$, it is very easy to see if it is the eigenstate of both $L^2$ and $L_z$. We just need to show that there exist numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that:
\begin{align}
L^2 | \psi \rangle &= \alpha | \psi \rangle \\
L_z | \psi \rangle &= \beta | \psi \rangle
\end{align}

In practice we would probably use coordinate representation to actually see if those relations hold or not.