# Show that if $\psi$ is an eigenfunction for the operator $A$ and $[A, B]\psi =0$ then $\psi$ is an eigenfunction for the operator B also

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator

> It is only possible for a state to have definite values for both $A$ and
> $B$ if the wave function $\psi$ satisfies $[A, B]\psi =0$.

This is a statement from Lectures on Quantum Mechanics by Weinberg and it is not an obvious statement. How to prove this? I am not asking for a rigorous proof, some intuitive proof is sufficient. Also $[A, B]\psi =0$ does not necessarily guarantee that A and B commute. I am not asking that if $B\psi =b\psi$ then show that the given condition will hold(That I know). I am asking to show that if the given condition is true then show that $B\psi =b\psi$. If you think that it is not true then give an example for operators A, B and $\psi$ where $\psi$ is not an eigenfunction for B.

Comment: @kaylimekay if A and B commute then [A,B]=0 and [A,B] operated on any function will give 0. But here it is give only for a function $\psi$. It may not be true for all functions.

Comment: OK thanks. That meaning wasn't clear to me from your post.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/606964/240866 does this answer your question?

Comment: @Monopole my question was similar but not exact. I know that if it is an eigenfunction for the other operator also then the given condition is easily satisfied and you explained only that. I am asking why it has to be an eigenfunction of the other operator? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Does 'definite value' in your question mean 'being an eigenfunction'?

Comment: @aneetkumar Yes later in that page he defined eigenfunction until that it was written like that.

Comment: The statement, as written, only says that "$\psi$ being an eigenfunction of $A$ and $B$" $\implies [A, B]\psi = 0$

Comment: @NiharKarve No it was clearly stated that -"It is only possible for a wavefunction $\psi$ to be eigenfunction for both A and B if the wave function $\psi$ satisfies [A,B]$\psi$=0."

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the implication that I have written means. Though it might not matter in this case, you need to be very careful with the direction of your implications. "X only if Y" means "X $\implies$ Y", not "Y $\implies$ X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question asked in the title and quoted in the post are different.
For the one in the title you have: $A\psi=\lambda \psi$ and $[A,B]\psi=0$ and asking if $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of $B$ -

$[A,B]\psi=0\Rightarrow AB\psi=BA\psi=B\lambda\psi=\lambda B\psi$

$\Rightarrow B\psi $ is an eigenfunction of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $A$ is non-degenerate in $\lambda$, then $B\psi=\alpha\psi$ for some $\alpha$. This means $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of $B$. This is what Nihar Karve answered.

For the one in the post, it says $A\psi=\lambda \psi$ $\&$ $B\psi=\mu\psi \Rightarrow[A,B]\psi=0$ for some $\lambda,\mu$.
It is straightforward to show this :

$AB\psi-BA\psi=A\mu\psi-B\lambda\psi=\mu A\psi-\lambda B\psi=\mu\lambda\psi-\lambda\mu\psi=0$

This is what Senor is trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\psi$ has a definite value for B if and only if $B|\psi\rangle = b|\psi\rangle$. That means:

$AB|\psi\rangle = A (b |\psi \rangle) = bA|\psi\rangle$

Using the same logic, of course, $A|\psi\rangle = a|\psi\rangle$, so $bA|\psi\rangle = ba|\psi\rangle $

From here you can see that $BA|\psi\rangle = ba|\psi\rangle$, making the commutator of A and B clearly 0. So if the wave function has definite values for A and B, the commutator just becomes the algebraic commutative property $ab - ba = 0$.

Comment: I know that if it is an eigenfunction for the other operator also then the given condition is easily satisfied and you explained only that. I am asking why it has to be an eigenfunction of the other operator? Why is it necessary?

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy The statement by Weinberg you quote is logically equivalent to “If $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of both $A$ and $B$, then $[A,B]\psi = 0$.” This is what this answer shows to be true.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy the statement here is using "if and only if" which is symmetric. So proving one proves the other and vice versa. There's nothing left to be proved. If $[A,B]\psi \neq 0$ then either $A|\psi> \neq a|\psi>$ or  $B|\psi> \neq b|\psi>$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $\hat{B}\psi$ is also the eigenfunction of $\hat{A}$. If the subspace in which $\psi$ lives is one dimensional, then $\hat{B}\psi$ is proportional to $\psi$, so $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of $\hat{B}$.

Comment: Yes, $B\psi$ is an eigenfunction for the operator A. Can you elaborate your remaining answer?

Comment: B$\psi$ has the same eigenvalue with $\psi$.

Comment: Yes, B$\psi$ has the same eigenvalue as $\psi$ with the operator A. But after that what are you telling?